# How to save image in folder ,when you convert binary image to string

Tags: php

I have tried to convert binary data into an image format and then save this image in a folder. I am using `imagesavealpha` function but it is not working.

My code is below:

```
<?php 
$image_data=file_get_contents('Logo.png');
$encoded_image=base64_encode($image_data);
$decoded_image=base64_decode($encoded_image);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($decoded_image);

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    $fileName ='/image/'.date('ymdhis').'.png'; 

    imagealphablending($im,false); 

    imagesavealpha($im, true);
?>
```

Comment: Set the flag to save full alpha channel information (as opposed to single-color transparency) when saving PNG images

Comment: Okay... and where in this code are you actually saving the image? Also, why are you getting the image's contents, encoding them, decoding them, and then loading them as a string? Why not just `imagecreatefrompng("Logo.png")`?

Comment: Actually i am creating web services  for iphone ... iphone user send me data as binary so i am using test image for that..

Comment: Okay, so the first two lines are just getting data in the format that your real code will expect. Gotcha. That still doesn't explain where your "save the image" call is.

Comment: I am not write  any code for save image ..i don't understand how to save image in folder

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`imagepng`](http://php.net/imagepng)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
$data = base64_decode($data);

file_put_contents('/tmp/image.png', $data);
```

or

```
file_put_contents('img.png', base64_decode($base64string));
```

Comment: Please repost answer.